# Calcular la edad de una persona en Java de Android

Tags: java, android, date

¿Cómo se puede obtener la edad de una persona teniendo su fecha de nacimiento en formato `Date`?

```
DateFormat dateFormat = dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
Date dob = dateFormat.parse("1989-10-10");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacer el cálculo. He aquí dos de ellas:

- **`java.time.chrono.ChronoPeriod`**

  Desde la API level 26 puede utilizarse el paquete `java.time`. Ejemplo:

  *Código:*

  ```
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd", 
          Locale.getDefault());
  ChronoLocalDate from = ChronoLocalDate.from(formatter.parse("1989-10-10"));
  ChronoLocalDate to = ChronoLocalDate.from(formatter.parse("2017-09-29"));
  ChronoPeriod period = ChronoPeriod.between(from, to);

  Formatter fmt = new Formatter();
  if (period.get(ChronoUnit.YEARS) > 0) {
      fmt.format("%d años ", period.get(ChronoUnit.YEARS));
  }
  if (period.get(ChronoUnit.MONTHS) > 0) {
      fmt.format("%d meses ", period.get(ChronoUnit.MONTHS));
  }
  if (period.get(ChronoUnit.DAYS) > 0) {
      fmt.format("%d días ", period.get(ChronoUnit.DAYS));
  }
  System.out.println(fmt.toString());
  ```

  *Salida:*

  ```
  27 años 11 meses 19 días
  ```
- **`java.util.GregorianCalendar`**

  También puede utilizarse `java.util.GregorianCalendar`, aunque no es tan preciso:

  *Código:*

  ```
  DateFormat dateFormat = dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", 
          Locale.getDefault());
  Date dob = dateFormat.parse("1989-10-10");
  GregorianCalendar cal = (GregorianCalendar) Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setGregorianChange(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE));
  cal.clear();
  cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 0);
  cal.setTimeInMillis( cal.getTimeInMillis() + new Date().getTime() - dob.getTime());

  Formatter fmtr = new Formatter();
  if (cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) > 0) {
      fmtr.format("%d años ", cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
  }
  if (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) > 0) {
      fmtr.format("%d meses ", cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
  }
  if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) > 0) {
      fmtr.format("%d días ", cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
  }
  System.out.println(fmtr.toString());
  ```

  *Salida:*

  ```
  27 años 11 meses 21 días
  ```

Comment: El primer ejemplo utiliza java.time de Java 8 que es soportado a partir de la API 26 (Oreo) aunque se puede utilizar en Apis menores agregando al gradle la dependencia:
compile 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.5'
En el ejemplo con Gregorian Calendar es para cualquier API. Esta demás en la primer línea un  dateFormat= . Y el parse de la fecha debe ser con un try catch.

Answer (score 3):

Un método sería aplicando el formato "yyyyMMdd" a la fecha de nacimiento y actual, se realiza una sustracción y se divide entre 1000, de esta forma podemos obtener la cantidad de años, para esto puedes realizar un método:

```
public  int getEdad(Date fechaNacimiento, Date fechaActual) {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    int dIni = Integer.parseInt(formatter.format(fechaNacimiento));
    int dEnd = Integer.parseInt(formatter.format(fechaActual));
    int age = (dEnd-dIni)/10000;
    return age;
}
```

y aplicarlo de esta forma, usando la fecha de nacimiento "1989-10-10" :

```
   try {
            DateFormat dateFormat = dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
            Date fechaNacimiento = dateFormat.parse("1989-10-10");
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date fechaActual = cal.getTime();

            System.out.println("Edad : " + String.valueOf(getEdad(fechaNacimiento, fechaActual)));

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

teniendo como salida:

```
Edad : 27
```